# Vue cookie-based authentication in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, laravel-sanctum, laravel-breeze

From reading the Laravel docs, it appears that when using Sanctum Vue will just use the cookie-based authentication.

I was trying to move an existing app (with login done using Livewire) to Vue, but calls direct to my first api endpoint were redirecting to the login page.

So I created a clean installation of Larvel, installed Breeze (with Inertia), then Sanctum, published the config etc.

But when I login and then visit my test endpoint (which just returns 200 Ok), it redirects to the login page (which, because I am logged in, redirects to the Breeze dashboard).

Do I need to do anything manually for my endpoint, guarded by `auth:sanctum`, to pass authentication?

**Update**

I've set `axios.defaults.withCredentials`, and it's returning `401 Unauthorized`. My app.js:

```js
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.get('/api/test')
    .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () {
        // always executed
    });
```

Comment: If you are using axios, you should enable the withCredentials option on your axios instance  `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;`.

Comment: Thanks @porloscerrosΨ - I'll give that a try. I was trying to load the api direct in my browser.

Comment: Oh ok. I don't know if the browser can directly handle the sanctum cookie. You have to get the sanctum cookie first. Then send the cookie on X-XSRF-TOKEN header.   If you use postman, [here](https://morioh.com/p/ed58563aa67a) is a smart implementation of that

Comment: Setting `withCredentials` didn't work. I'll watch the tutorial you've linked.

Comment: Actually, `withCredentials` did work! I'd changed it to try the out of the box `/user` endpoint, which uses `auth:api` rather than `auth:sanctum`.

@porloscerrosΨ thank you, add it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ensure that your application's CORS configuration is returning the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header with a value of `True`. This may be accomplished by setting the `supports_credentials` option within your application's `config/cors.php` configuration file to `true`.

Then, if you are using axios, you should enable the `withCredentials` option on your axios instance:

```
axios.get('some api url', {withCredentials: true});
```

or globally:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

If you are not using Axios to make HTTP requests from your frontend, you should perform the equivalent configuration on your own [HTTP client](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials).

Laravel Docs [Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#cors-and-cookies).

---

If you are using Postman to test your api, [here](https://morioh.com/p/ed58563aa67a) is a smart implementation of sanctum authentication requests. Basically you have to get the sanctum cookie first, and then send the cookie on `XSRF-TOKEN` header.